# Django static files and Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, production

In my main project directory I have a settings directory which has the following files: `local.py`, `base.py`, `production.py` and `__init__.py`. On running collectstatic files are saved in the folder staticfiles in the project directory

`local.py`

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__) 

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

`base.py`

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__) 

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

`production.py`

```
import os
from django.conf import settings


DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Static asset configuration
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

When I run the following command:
`heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

I am getting the error: `You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

Comment: Do exactly what the error message says. `STATIC_ROOT` is meant to be a directory on your file system and you've got it set like a web directory. Did you mean `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`?

Comment: So is the following the way to do it: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)`

Comment: I use STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'assets')) personally, but it looks like you have TBA's suggestion right.  Also, take a look at [Django Whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise)

Answer (score 0):

A good template / guide for deploying on Heroku is [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template).

Take a look at their settings.py torwards the end::

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it still does not work. It is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a relative path in the STATIC_ROOT in your production.py file.

Use it like your do in your base.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```